# Ubuntu 14.04 - PHP socket_create doesn't create port to listen

Tags: php, sockets, ubuntu

I am trying to move my first php web_socket app to the server. It works fine on my local PC. But when I start it on the server I cant see socket port when I execute "netstat -tupln" command in the cmd.
This is the code of the php script:

```
$address='185.86.78.52';//<!-- I tried to put here domain name and 127.0.0.1 but it didn't help
$port=99887;
$socket=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
if($socket===false){
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."<br />\r\n";
    die();
}
else echo "socket created\r\n";
socket_set_option($socket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,1);
socket_bind($socket,$address,$port);
socket_listen($socket);
//socket_create_listen($port);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);
echo "socket initiated\r\n";
```

It returns "socket created\r\nsocket initiated\r\n" without any errors so I assume that this part of code works. But if I'm trying to check the port with "netstat -tupln" I cant see it. Also when I try to connect to the socket from my browser with this code

```
new WebSocket('ws://185.86.78.52:99887/sockets/webrtc.php')
```

I have this response from server "WebSocket connection to 'ws://185.86.78.52:99887/sockets/webrtc.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

Can you point me what is wrong here and why it doesn't work?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that I had iptables rules. This commands solved my problem:

```
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 55533 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 55533 -j ACCEPT
```

55533 - is a port number to open.